# SIP News List not reading databound items?

Tags: sitecore, sip, ascx, databound

I simply removed the `imgNewsList` field from my `Intranet.WebPart.NewsList.ascx` and now it seems like my News List on the frontpage doesn't read my databound fields properly.

It just looks like this:

```
<%# Eval("MenuTitle")%> 
<%# Eval("ShortIntro") %>" etc.
```

I tried simply putting the deleted code back into the page, but it still doesn't work.

I am doing this in the Developer Center. Is it somehow formating the code in a wrong way or what is causing this?

**Edit:**
I tried setting my NewsList GridView to `AutoGenerateColumns=True`, and it shows all data without any problem. So there is a connection to the database. I actually thought that was the problem. It's like it doesn't understand the Eval command any longer, because when I want to define which fields to show myself by using Eval, it just shows the Eval tags as plain text in the News List on my frontpage.

Comment: Don't use the Developer Center. Open it in Visual Studio. It's probably formatted wrong if you see the actual Eval code on the front-end of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out Developer Center ruins the formatting, just like Mark Ursino said in his comment. It works when i just manually upload the file, instead of saving it through Developer Center.